# Create flip toggle from code

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

I`m trying to create flip toggle from code.

```
var favFlip = '<label for="favourFlip">To fav:</label>'+
        '<select id="favourFlip" data-role="slider">'+
            '<option value="off">Off</option>'+
            '<option value="on">On</option>'+
        '</select>';
        $('.ui-content').append(favFlip);
var flip = $('#favourFlip');
flip.slider('refresh');
```

This code work in `pagebeforeshow` handler and throw error: `Uncaught cannot call methods on slider prior to initialization; attempted to call method 'refresh'`. How fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may want to try running it in `pageshow`, then the DOM is certainly loaded and your container for `$('#favourFlip')` will be initialized.

Edit: Try: `.slider()`. You do this because you are creating a slider object and not updating an already existing one.
Example: http://jsfiddle.net/Calavoow/724yH/3/

Comment: Unfortunately no, container initialized perfectly